# Comment traduire « refreshingly » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais

Je n'arrive pas à trouver une traduction satisfaisante de l'adverbe anglais *refreshingly*, souvent utilisé pour souligner le côté appréciablement inhabituel de quelque chose ; par exemple :

> My colleague was refreshingly honest when I asked her for feedback.

Je suppose qu'on pourrait commencer par essayer de traduire l'adjectif *refreshing*... En tout cas l'adverbe semble laborieux à exprimer en français, alors qu'il s'utilise simplement en anglais. Voir par exemple tous les [extraits proposés par Linguee](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/refreshingly.html), où la traduction à chaque fois perd ou appauvrit le sens exprimé par *refreshingly* (je trouve).

Comment traduire cette notion en français ?

Comment: I sometimes use «welcomingly [honest]» to mean about the same thing as «refreshingly [honest]» in English so maybe you could expand your search to include an adverb based on “bienvenu/e” the adjective.  I did find a few instances of & one entry for [“bienvenuement”](http://conjf.cactus2000.de/show_adj.fr.php?adj=bienvenu), but I doubt if it’s a real word and the related [“opportunément”](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/opportun%C3%A9ment/56217) doesn’t seem to jive with the way I use “welcomingly” in place of “refreshingly.”

Comment: @Ange-à-Liberté Frankly, I wouldn't know how to answer those good questions but they did make me think of another possible purpose that "refreshingly" could be serving here: as a sentential adverb along the lines of "thankfully" or "fortunately" (and the debatable "hopefully") and if so then perhaps "Refreshingly" could have even started the sentence without changing its meaning by much.

Comment: @PapaPoule That sentential adverb is functionally equivalent to what I had in mind. J'ai posé une [question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/112043) sur _ELL_ pour voir. Merci !

Comment: Le feedback [retour d'information ou d'expérience, si l'on veut] que j'ai demandé à ma collègue change un peu des réponses usuelles que l'on reçoit. A mon avis, il faut prendre l'idée et la reformuler et éviter en tout état de cause des mots comme rafraîchissant et companie. Aucun mot tout seul ne fera l'affaire....

Comment: As a French native speaker, I feel a bit reluctant to the two answers which bring like an evidence that _the involved colleague_ is usually not so honest. Sure it might be true, but without more information about him, my most obvious understanding is that "refreshingly" here rather targets people in general, as well explained by @Papa Poule. Anyway the most accurate mean of "refreshing" is "rafraîchissant", while "inattendu" already takes account of an a priori against the colleague.

Answer (score 2):

We may say

```
Il était d'une honnêteté rafraîchissante.
```

http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-french/refreshingly%20honest

Different usage of the adverb:

```
refreshingly honest: d'une honnêteté rafraîchissante
⇒ He was refreshingly honest. Il était d'une honnêteté rafraîchissante.

refreshingly simple: d'une simplicité rafraîchissante

refreshingly different: d'une originalité rafraîchissante
```

Answer (score 2):

> Ma collègue s’est montrée franche, **pour changer** ...
>
> **Pour une fois**, ma collègue s’est montrée franche ...

Je crois qu'il se traduit bien par « pour changer, pour une fois », compte tenu du fait que l'on emploie "refreshing/refreshingly" en anglais quand quelqu'un fait preuve de courage/gentillesse/honnêteté/etc,  côté auquel l'on ne s'attendait pas chez lui, et si l'on souhaite qu'il en soit ainsi plus souvent.

Qui plus est, le verbe « se montrer » sert à renforcer la nature inhabituelle et ponctuelle.

Answer (score 2):

Without an obvious way to translate with a single word the fact it was both unexpected and pleasant, I would rephrase the sentence that way:

> J'ai **beaucoup apprécié** la franchise **inattendue** de mon collègue lorsque je lui ai demandé son avis.

Answer (score 2):

To the extent that you would really like to maintain the adverbial feel that “refreshingly” has in your English example, perhaps you could consider trying to fit the **“de/d’une façon +adjective** [rafraîchissante, in this case]” construction somewhere into the translation, such as:

> Ma collègue s’est montrée franche/honnête/ouverte, **de/d’une façon
>   rafraîchissante**, lorsque je lui ai demandé son avis.

or

> **De/D’une façon rafraîchissante**, ma collègue s’est montrée franche/honnête/ouverte lorsque je lui ai demandé son avis.

You’ll perhaps note that these suggestions are similar in form to @Ah alone-zee ’s good answer (and that I’ve also borrowed “s’est montrée franche” from that answer [as well as “lorsque je lui ai demandé son avis” from jlliagre’s]).
However, perhaps my suggested choice of words doesn’t imply quite as much as Ah alone-zee’s (to me, at least) that **this particular** colleague is usually not frank, but instead that people/colleagues **in general** are often less than frank.
Therefore, **perhaps** my choice would be more appropriate **if** this colleague is actually being commended for being an exception to this general rule/observation and not being indirectly/backhandedly chastised for her particular prior lack of honesty.

(cf: as an aside relating to my earlier comment above that I sometimes use “welcomingly” instead of “refreshingly,” perhaps you could use “De/D’une façon bienvenue” instead of “De/D’une façon rafraîchissante” in either of the above suggestions without changing their meaning too much)